# Зацикливание в админке WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Создаю тему.
На данный момент функционала никакого в ней толком нет.

**Реализовано**

1. Вывод меню
2. Вывод сайдбара
3. slick слайдер
4. кнопка отобразить\скрыть адаптивное меню

если нужно - могу предоставить любой код

---

**Описание проблемы**

При выборе моей темы и переходе в админке в раздел Внешний вид -> Настроить - возникает ошибка: сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз. После удаления кэша и куки эта проблема иногда исчезает до следующего обновления страницы. В браузере установлен только Cache Killer, при его отключении - проблема остается.
**Установленные плагины:**

1. ACF
2. Hello Dolly

Дефолтные темы работают нормально.

Никаких редиректов в htacces я не писал, перенаправлений с http на https я не делал.
Смотрел по консоли, отловил этот редирект в заголовках пришло **Provisional headers are shown**.

Ошибку эту гуглил, но вот причина ее возникновения - осталась непонятной, так как писалось выше - никаких редиректов я не делал.

Ошибка исчезает только в том случае если в настройках пермалинков поставить вариант "обычные". Но мне в этот вариант решения не подходит, к тому же в дефолтных темах этой проблемы нет, значит проблема в моей теме.

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу найти причину возникновения этой ошибки, как ее можно устранить. Гуглёж почти никак не помог.

код моего .htaccess (который находится в корне WP)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Если есть кастомные скрипты, попробуйте отключить по очереди. Проверьте функции в functions.php. Комментируйте и смотрите, что изменилось.

Comment: По кастомным скриптам: Jquery встроенный отключил, из остальных скриптов: переключатель класса по клику и слайдер. В functions.php только вывод меню и подключение сайдбара.